# Question about finding an example

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I want to find an element $v$ from $H^1(\Omega)$ where

$H^1(\Omega)=\{u\in L^2(\Omega), \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\in L^2(\Omega), i=1,\ldots,N\}$, $\Omega$ is a bounded from $\mathbb{R}^N.$

such that $v^{\alpha}\notin H^1(\Omega), \alpha >1$ .

Comment: What is $H^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: @gunbl4d3 i edited my question: $H^1(\Omega)=\{u\in L^2(\Omega), \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\in L^2(\Omega), i=1,\ldots,N\}$, $\Omega$ is a bounded from $\mathbb{R}^N.$

Comment: one suggest to me to take $v$ with a singularity, but i don't know how ?@gunbl4d3

Comment: any idea @gunbl4d3 ?

Comment: You might want to play around with the function $1/|x|^\beta$ defined on a unit ball $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ . This function belongs to $H^1(B)$ for certain values of $\beta$ that depends on $N$.

Comment: @CheeHan i work on$\Omega=(0,1)$ and i found the condition on $\beta$ is less then $-\frac12$ is it logical ?

Comment: @CheeHan i found $\beta<-\frac12$ and $\alpha<1$ which is not what i'm looing for if you find an examole please tel me

Comment: As I mentioned before, $\beta$ should depends on $N$. I believe the following more general result is true. Let $B\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be the unit ball, and consider the function $u(x)=|x|^{-\beta}, \beta>0$. Then $u\in W^{1,p}$ for $p\in [1,\infty)$ if and only if $(\beta + 1)p<N$, where $W^{1,p}$ is the usual Sobolev space. In your case, $H^1(B)$ corresponds to $W^{1,2}(B)$.

Comment: @CheeHan and $|u|^{-\alpha\beta}$  to be not in $H^1$ we must have $(\alpha\beta+1)>\frac{N}{2}$ right ?

Comment: Yes it is a necessary and sufficient condition. So choose $\beta$ within the range, then take $\alpha$ large enough so that $(\alpha\beta+1)>N/2$. This will work since you require $\alpha>1$.

Comment: please can you explain me how we find the condition $(\beta+1)p<N$ thank you@CheeHan

Comment: The idea is that when you evaluate $\int_B |u|^p$ for example, you convert from Cartesian to polar coordinate, then use the fact that $\int_0^1 r^a\, dr$ converges if and only if $a>-1$. A similar argument applies to evaluating $\int_B |\nabla u|^p$.